# How to get locale id in iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, delphi

I need to get the locale id like the one returned by Windows:

```
GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_ILANGUAGE, PChar(locale), 256)
```

for iOS and Android. I need that for SQL Server collation info (LCID).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access to the device locale service use the [`TPlatformServices`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.Platform.TPlatformServices) and the [`IFMXLocaleService`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXLocaleService) interface.

```
uses
  FMX.Platform;
...
...
var
  LService: IFMXLocaleService;
  LangID  : string;
begin
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXLocaleService, IInterface(LService)) then
    LangID := LService.GetCurrentLangID;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function `GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_ILANGUAGE, PChar(locale), 256)` will return [Windows specific LCID code number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318693(v=vs.85).aspx).

For instance for US English it will return `0409` hex code, where `09` marks primary language ID (en) and `04` is sort order identifier. [Windows Locale Identifiers Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373763(v=vs.85).aspx)

Problem is that you cannot get such number on other platforms, and you would have to create custom lookout tables to map platform locale (you can find platform locale using @RRUZ answer) to Windows one.

The best you can get is on OS X, where you can get primary Windows Locale ID with following code:

```
uses
  Macapi.Foundation;

var
  WinID: integer;

   WinID := TNSLocale.OCClass.windowsLocaleCodeFromLocaleIdentifier(TNSLocale.Wrap(TNSLocale.OCClass.currentLocale).localeIdentifier);
```

In case of US English above function will return `0009` hex code.

Comment: That's exactly what I need, by using proper locale in packet I can skip translating user locale ANSI string into server one (seems AutoTranslate option in OLEDB). And thanks for explanation of LCID. TDS have 5 bytes per collation where 20 bits (wonder why so many, can't find locale above 65535) LCID, flags and last one byte is another sort order.